# PHP representing any number

Tags: php, html, menu

I got this menu made with some php help in order to add `.active` depending on the page request.

Like this:

```
<ul class="menu_lateral">
    <li><a <?php if(($_REQUEST['p']=="estufas") || ($_REQUEST['p']=="estufas-1")){?> class="active" <?php } ?> href="index.php?p=estufas">Estufas</a></li>
    <li><a <?php if($_REQUEST['p']=="recuperadores"){?> class="active" <?php } ?> href="index.php?p=recuperadores">Recuperadores</a></li>
    <li><a <?php if($_REQUEST['p']=="salamandras"){?> class="active" <?php } ?> href="index.php?p=salamandras">Salamandras</a></li>
    <li><a <?php if($_REQUEST['p']=="churrasqueiras"){?> class="active" <?php } ?> href="index.php?p=churrasqueiras">Churrasqueiras</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see on the first item, there is another ESTUFA page. So if the request is ESTUFAS it will add the `.active` and also add it if the request is ESTUFAS-1.

The thing is, I want to add a lot of pages, estufas-1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc and to do so I would have to add a lot of OR's to my If or maybe change it to a Case Of. But that seems to be too much work and it will not be dynamical.

Is there any way to get it to be any number, for example:

```
if(($_REQUEST['p']=="estufas") || ($_REQUEST['p']=="estufas-ANYNUMBER"))
```

So it would add `.active` if the request was estufas or estufas-1 or estufas-2 or estufas-3, etc.

That would make things so simple.

Is there any way to do that? Or any other solution?

Comment: Write a function to do this and call that

Comment: a for loop to1,2,3...

Comment: Modify your request to have two values (e.g. `?p=estufas&v=3`) then `$_REQUEST['p']` will still be `estufas` but you'll also have a `$_REQUEST['v']` where `v` is your ANYNUMBER

Comment: Look up `substr()` in the [Manual](http://php.net/substr) to solve your **ANYNUMBER** requirement. Although @MarkBaker idea is much better

Comment: @JohnConde that's a really nice idea. Can you help me with that? How can I create a function that returns a variable that can represent any number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use something like [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to find if it's there

```
if(stripos($_REQUEST['p'], 'estufas') !== false) // We have estufas
```

Comment: This one seems to be the fastest and easiest way to do it. Have my Acception.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code inside if condition:

```
preg_match('/^estufas(-\d)?$/', $_REQUEST['p'])
```

So result will be:

```
<ul class="menu_lateral">
    <li><a <?php if(preg_match('/^estufas(-\d)?$/', $_REQUEST['p'])){?> class="active" <?php } ?> href="index.php?p=estufas">Estufas</a></li>
    <li><a <?php if($_REQUEST['p']=="recuperadores"){?> class="active" <?php } ?> href="index.php?p=recuperadores">Recuperadores</a></li>
    <li><a <?php if($_REQUEST['p']=="salamandras"){?> class="active" <?php } ?> href="index.php?p=salamandras">Salamandras</a></li>
    <li><a <?php if($_REQUEST['p']=="churrasqueiras"){?> class="active" <?php } ?> href="index.php?p=churrasqueiras">Churrasqueiras</a></li>
</ul>
```